# Error: $injector:undef Undefined Value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

The response of ajax is like `["99636941","74167247"]`. But the values are not accepted by angularjs. The response is ok. If I declare the same response as static, then it is working properly.

```
app.factory("States", function(){
    var states;
    $.ajax({
        url:'php/usersList.php',
        type:'post',
        success:function(data,status)
        { 
            states = data;
            console.log(states);
        },
        error:function(xhr,desc,err)
        {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: "+ desc + "\n error:"+err);
        }
    });
    return states;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to note:

- Do not use jQuery ajax `$.ajax` in angularjs service - use `$http` instead as it will handle digest cycle by itself. Read: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
- As you are making an ajax call, `return states` will get executed even before your ajax success event - try looking into Promises in javascript/angular js.

You may refactor this method like:

```
    app.factory("States", function($http){

     var getStates function(){
      return $http.post('php/usersList.php');//ideally this should be a GET method
     };

     return {
        getStates: getStates
     }
    });
```

And in theplace where you call this method:

```
var states;
States.getStates().then(function(data){
  states = data;
})
```

Comment: thank for the answer, but my question how can i use getstates() from another controller.While i am using states values in controller.

Comment: @krishna - thats what the second piece of code is doing. Inject your factory in your controller and call `States.getStates().then(function(data){
  states = data;
})`

Answer (score 0):

If we make it more simpler, You can do it the following way.

```
app.factory("States", function($http){

 var factory={};
 factory.getStates=function($http){
  return $http({
        method:'GET',
        url:'your URL'
    });
 };
 /*similarly write as many functions as you need and then simply return the factory var*/
 return factory;
});
```